# Powerful Website Monitoring App for many different websites

Tags: open-source, web

Has to be open source. Most of our websites are build with WordPress, but not all of them.
Should have these, but in general many features (if features can be implemented with 3rd party tools, that's ok:
Should support many different websites
Uptime check
Identify needed updates (Stuff like PHP, WordPress, plugins, ...)
Should automatically report any Issues to an email address
should automatically assign priorities to alerts (would be fine if you can define types, and we can assign those types a priority)
Should make automated health checks (over a 3rd party tool would be fine)
Should be connectable (at least via email) with webhosters, for stuff like renewing SSL Zertificats, ...
Will likely be selfhosted